# How to Maintain Aspect Ratio when Adding an Image to a PDFButtonFormField using iText7

Tags: java, image, pdf, itext

I am collecting images from users with a form field on a PDF form. When the field is empty the user can populated the field in Acrobat and I can successfully read it from the form using iText7. If the user has previously uploaded an image, I want to present them with that image alreadyloaded into the form field and allow them to select and submit a different image. iText allows me to populate the form with the image but I distorts the image's aspect ration by resizing it to the dimensions of the form field's rectangle.

Is there a way to get iText's `setImage()` method to maintain the aspect ratio when loading the image?

I have also tried using the following code to modify the form field's rectangle to conform to the image aspect ratio before loading the image:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("TestForm.pdf");
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(os);
StampingProperties properties = new StampingProperties();
properties.useAppendMode();
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader, writer, properties);
PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(document, false);
acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true);

//  get button form field
String fieldName = "Image1_af_image";
PdfButtonFormField field = (PdfButtonFormField)acroForm.getField(fieldName);
//  retrieve widget rectangle
PdfDictionary widgets = field.getWidgets().get(0).getPdfObject();
com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle rect = widgets.getAsRectangle(PdfName.Rect);
//  modify its width
field.setImage("/Users/sschultz/Desktop/zuni logo.jpg").setFieldName(fieldName);

document.close();
os.flush();
os.close();
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("TestForm_out.pdf"), os.toByteArray());
```

but this code fails to modify the form field's original dimensions.

Finally, I have attempted to add a second, new form field with the appropriate aspect ratio:

```
//  add second button field to form
String fieldName2 = "Image2_af_image";
PdfButtonFormField imageField = PdfFormField.createButton(document, new Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 50),
        PdfButtonFormField.FF_PUSH_BUTTON);
imageField.setImage("image2.jpg").setFieldName(fieldName2);
acroForm.addField(imageField);
```

but the second field never appears in the form.

Answer (score 4):

The default behavior of drawing button field appearance that doesn't preserve image's aspect ratio is quite complicated to override. Instead I can suggest to generate appearance manually, making it exactly as you want it.

```
// get widget dictionary
List<PdfWidgetAnnotation> widgets = pushButtonField.getWidgets();
PdfDictionary widgetDict;
if (widgets.size() > 0) {
    widgetDict = widgets.get(0).getPdfObject();
} else {
    // widgets.size() == 0 shouldn't really happen to properly created
    // existing fields, but let's do it just in case
    widgetDict = pushButtonField.getPdfObject();
}
Rectangle origRect = widgetDict.getAsRectangle(PdfName.Rect);
float borderWidth = pushButtonField.getBorderWidth();

String imgPath = ... // path to image file

// draw custom appearance preserving original field sizes
PdfFormXObject pdfFormXObject = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(origRect.getWidth() - borderWidth * 2, origRect.getHeight() - borderWidth * 2));
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfFormXObject, pdfDoc);
// Image class preserves aspect ratio by default
Image image = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(imgPath))
        .setAutoScale(true)
        .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
Div container = new Div()
        .setMargin(borderWidth).add(image)
        .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
        .setFillAvailableArea(true);
canvas.add(container);
canvas.close();

// override original appearance with new one
PdfDictionary apDict = new PdfDictionary();
widgetDict.put(PdfName.AP, apDict);
apDict.put(PdfName.N, pdfFormXObject.getPdfObject());

// mark widgetDict as modified in order to save its changes in append mode
widgetDict.setModified();
```

The last line (calling `setModified()`) is required to be done for all low level `PdfObject`s modifications if you are using `properties.useAppendMode();`. Otherwise the change will be not saved.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me, although I adopted to use in C#.